# PHP Overloading

Tags: php, overloading

I've sort of created my own framework to develop my personal portfolio website. I've based it (very) loosely on Zend Framework, which I am fairly familiar with. I've managed to get things working apart from setting variables within the controller which can then be used in the .phtml files. This is what I have at the moment (e.g. url here is www.mydomain.com/services/hosting):

front.php

```
class front {
    private $sControllerName = 'home';
    private $sActionName = 'index';

    function __construct() {
        $this->view = new viewProperties();
        $aUriParts = $this->getUriParts();
        if (!empty($aUriParts[0])) {
            $this->sControllerName = $aUriParts[0];   
        }
        if (!empty($aUriParts[1])) {
            $this->sActionName = $aUriParts[1];   
        }
        $this->constructController();
        include('path/to/views/view.phtml');
    }

    private function constructController() {
        $sContFile = 'controllers/'.$this->sControllerName.'.php';
        if (@include($sContFile)) {
            $c = new $this->sControllerName();
            // Action method, if exists
            $this->doAction($c);
        }
    }

    public function getElement($name) {
        include('public_html/elements/'.$name);
    }

    public function renderContent() {
        $sViewFile = 'path/to/views/'.$this->sControllerName;
        if ($this->sActionName) {
            $sViewFile .= '/'.$this->sActionName.'.phtml';
        } else {
            $sViewFile .= '.php';
        }
        if (!@include($sViewFile)) {
            $this->render404();
        }
    }

    private function doAction($c) {
        $sActionFunc = str_replace('-', '_', $this->sActionName.'Action');
        if (method_exists($c,$sActionFunc)) {
            $c->$sActionFunc();
        }
    }

    private function render404() {
        include('path/to/views/404.phtml');
    }

    private function getUriParts() {
        $sUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $sUri = trim($sUri, "/");
        $sUri = str_replace("-", "_", $sUri);
        $aUriParts = explode("/", $sUri);
        return $aUriParts;
    }
}
```

viewProperties.php

```
class viewProperties {
    static $_instance = null;
    private $data = array();

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo "Setting '$name' to '$value'\n";
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        echo "Getting '$name'\n";
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        echo "Is '$name' set?\n";
        return isset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    public function __unset($name) {
        echo "Unsetting '$name'\n";
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }
}
```

services.php

```
class services extends controller {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->view->banner->src = '/path/to/images/banners/home_02.jpg';
        $this->view->banner->alt = 'banner title';
    }

    public function hostingAction() {
        $this->view->banner->src = '/path/to/images/banners/home_02.jpg';
        $this->view->banner->alt = 'banner title';
    }
}
```

in hosting.phtml I have:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->view->banner->src ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->view->banner->title ?>" />
```

How can I set properties (not just for a banner) in the controller and then retrieve them in the view? Help/guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: what is exactly the question?

Comment: Sorry for being so vague. How can I set properties (not just for a banner) in the controller and then retrieve them in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify exactly what problem you are experiencing, I will have to guess from the code.

I am guessing that you are not currently able to set/retrieve the banner properties?

If so, try this:

```
class services extends controller {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->view->banner = array
        (
            'src' => '/path/to/images/banners/home_02.jpg',
            'alt' => 'banner title'
         );
    }

    public function hostingAction() {
        $this->view->banner = array
        (
            'src' => '/path/to/images/banners/home_02.jpg',
            'alt' => 'banner title'
        );
    }
}

<img src="<?php echo $this->view->banner['src'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->view->banner['title'] ?>" />
```

This is a simple fix to achieve a working model, but not exactly what you were aiming for.

To create a dynamic variable that would allow you to access multiple levels via '->' you would probably need to create a `ViewElement` type that wrapped the resulting assignment and supplied the _* methods.

In your example, `banner` has not actually been created (i.e. `_set()` is never called) before it is retrieved via `_get()` - so your code needs to auto-create a value when `_get()` is called on a non-existing value.

I also recommend that your ViewProperties extend ViewElement to reduce duplicated code.

Here's something I whipped up (the magic is in `__get()` ):

```
class viewProperties extends ViewElement {
    static $_instance = null;
    private $data = array ();
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self ();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
class ViewElement {
    private $data = array ();
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo "Setting '$name' to '$value'\n";
        $this->data [$name] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name) {
        echo "Getting '$name'\n";
        if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $this->data )) {
            $this->data [$name] = new ViewElement();
        }
        return $this->data [$name];
    }
    public function __isset($name) {
        echo "Is '$name' set?\n";
        return isset ( $this->data [$name] );
    }
    public function __unset($name) {
        echo "Unsetting '$name'\n";
        unset ( $this->data [$name] );
    }
}

$view = viewProperties::getInstance();
$view->boo = "hoo";
$view->foo->bar = "baz";
print ("boo = '{$view->boo}', foo->bar='{$view->foo->bar}'");
```

[edit] Fat-fingered and submitted before complete.

[edit] Expanding answer with possible solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @David Farrel! I'm able to be setting the properties now. But how can I access these in my view.phtml?

Comment: The view.phtl has the doctype and <head> tags and I want to be able to customise these from the controller action.

I've tried putting `$view = viewProperties::getInstance();` in front.php but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: I would need to know more about how you are including your .phtml files, but off-hand, I see the one your provided in your question has `$this->view->...` and unless you are executing this .phtml within a class file, `$this` has no meaning.  If it is just being executed normally, then adding `<?php $view = viewProperties::getInstance() ?>` at the top of the file to bring $view into scope (or not if $view is a global variable), and replace `$this->view->...` with just `$view->...` might do the trick.

Comment: See front.php in my originally posted code. view.phtml is included in the __construct function in front.php In view.phtml I the function call "renderContent" which includes the specific content for the page.

Comment: I recommend making your instance variables explicit - You appear to want a $view on the `front` and `controller` classes.  I would add 'private $view' to both classes.  Also, I don't see any code that is passing a $view to the controller instance?  You probably need either a `setView($view)` method or a constructor that takes $view as a parameter.  Also you didn't update your original post with the additional `ViewElement` class I provided (can you update it if its closed?) but unless you do, you can't have the magic that sets `view->banner->src` without banner having been previously defined.

Comment: Also, I can only assume that `include('path/to/views/view.phtml');` is where "hosting.phtml" gets included?  Does this mean there was a "view.phtml" file that wasn't included in your post (that then includes "hosting.phtml"), or that its just pseudo code (in which case I would rather see actual code that you are trying to make work instead of pseudo code)

Comment: You may have noticed that I have asked this question again here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617336/access-properties-in-view-phtml-file-that-have-been-set-in-the-controller

I think I wasn't thorough enough the first time round.

I've decided that trying to create properties like $view->banner->src is too complicated and will cause extras unnecessary work, so am going to stick with $view->banner_src