# Access properties in View phtml file that have been set in the Controller

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, overloading

I am working on a small PHP website which is based on MVC. I have a front controller (`front.php`) which loads the controller (`services.php`), runs the action method (`hostingAction()`) and includes the html (`view.phtml`). There is a method call in view.phtml (`$this->renderContent()`) that includes the inner content (`hosting.phtml`).

QUESTION:
How can I set properties (e.g. `$title = 'My Title';`) in the `hostingAction()` method and then in view.phtml do `<title><?php echo $title ?></title>`?

Zend Framework does something like `$this->view->title = 'My Title';` in the controller and then in the view does something like `<title><?php echo $view->title; ?></title>`.

Currently I am overloading the properties. I am managing to set the properties in the controller action but failing to access them in my view. What am I doing wrong here?

SAMPLE CODE:

front.php

```
class front {

    private $view;

    function __construct() {

        $this->view = new viewProperties();    
        $this->constructController();
        include('application/views/view.phtml');
    }


    private function constructController() {

        $c = new services();
        $this->doAction($c);
    }


    public function renderContent() {

        include('application/views/services/hosting.php');
    }


    private function doAction($c) {

        $c->hostingAction();
    }
}
```

services.php

```
class services {

    public function hostingAction() {

        $this->view->page_title = 'Services - Hosting';
        $this->view->banner_src = '/assets/images/banners/home_02.jpg';
        $this->view->banner_title = 'reload';
    }
}
```

viewProperties.php

```
class viewProperties {

    private $data = array ();

    public function __set($name, $value) {

        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }


    public function __get($name) {

        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

view.phtml

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $this->view->page_title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php $this->renderContent() ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

hosting.phtml

```
<div id="banner">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->view->banner_src ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->view->banner_title ?>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Services` object does not have access to `$view`.

Try these mods:

**front.php** (with setter)

```
class front {

    private function constructController() {
        $c = new services();
        $c->setView($this->view);
        $this->doAction($c);
    }
}
```

**services.php** (with setter)

```
class services {
    private $view;

    public function setView(viewProperties $view) {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function hostingAction() {

        $this->view->page_title = 'Services - Hosting';
        $this->view->banner_src = '/assets/images/banners/home_02.jpg';
        $this->view->banner_title = 'reload';
    }
}
```

## Using a Singleton

Also, you could make viewProperties a singleton (per your comments):

**viewProperties** (with singleton)

```
class viewProperties {

    private $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === $this->instance) {
            $this->instance = new self();
        }
        return $this->view;
    }
}
```

**front** (with singleton)

```
class front {

    private $view;

    function __construct() {

        $this->view = viewProperties::getInstance();
        $this->constructController();
        include('application/views/view.phtml');
    }
}
```

**services.php** (with singleton)

```
class services {

    private $view;

    function __construct() {
        $view = viewProperties::getInstance();
    }

    public function hostingAction() {

        $this->view->page_title = 'Services - Hosting';
        $this->view->banner_src = '/assets/images/banners/home_02.jpg';
        $this->view->banner_title = 'reload';
    }
}
```

## Using Multi-dimensional Variables

Finally, in regards to you using 'banner_src' and 'banner_title', You can use the method I mentioned in your original post, which scales better.

**NOTE** The example below was copied from my reply to your original post, and has not been fixed to match your new code.  It is showing that you can store arrays() for multidimensional data and shows how to access them from your view.

```
class services extends controller {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->view->banner = array
        (
            'src' => '/path/to/images/banners/home_02.jpg',
            'alt' => 'banner title'
         );
    }

    public function hostingAction() {
        $this->view->banner = array
        (
            'src' => '/path/to/images/banners/home_02.jpg',
            'alt' => 'banner title'
        );
    }
}

<img src="<?php echo $this->view->banner['src'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->view->banner['title'] ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick. One question though. Rather than passing `$view` to `services` can I not (within `services`) look to see if an instance of viewProperties exists and get that?

Comment: Yes, you could make viewProperties a Singleton - I've updated my answer with an example (untested, so parden any syntax errors).

Comment: Also, please be sure to 'Accept' my answer since it did the trick :) Thanks!